# How do i store select value into a php variable

Tags: php

i have a simple drop down select menu.

```
<div id="select">
<select class="select">
  <option value="year 1">year 1</option>
  <option value="year 2">year 2</option>
  <option value="year 3">year 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

How do i take the value that the user selects and store it into a php variable?

Comment: Also: You don't need `value="..."` on an `option` tag if the value is exactly the same as the label

Comment: do you want to store the value after post on in the same page?

Comment: same page, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in somephpfile.php

```
$selected = $_POST['somename'];
```

html

```
 <form action="somephpfile.php" method="post"> 
    <div id="select">
    <select class="select">
    <select name="somename"> <!-- you missed this -->
      <option value="year 1">year 1</option>
      <option value="year 2">year 2</option>
      <option value="year 3">year 3</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: sorry for asking such a beginner question, but thank you this really helped.

Comment: sorry, do i need to tag the whole select with form, then give the form tag the name for this post to work? (<form name="somename"><select></select></form>)

Comment: <form action="somephpfile.php" method="post">

Answer (score 2):

you missed the "name" attribut in the select and the form tag. Try this:

```
<HTML><BODY>

<?PHP
  $sel_year= $_POST['select'];

  echo $sel_year
?>


<FORM method="post" action="...your-php-file-name-here...">

<div id="select">
<select name="select">
  <option value="year 1">year 1</option>
  <option value="year 2">year 2</option>
  <option value="year 3">year 3</option>
</select>
</div>

</FORM>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div id="select">
<select class="select" name="selectoptionname">
  <option value="year 1">year 1</option>
  <option value="year 2">year 2</option>
  <option value="year 3">year 3</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>
```

when form submits you can get the value of selected option using  `$_POST['selectoptionname']`

Answer (score 0):

put it in a form , then use $_POST['select']