# How do I put javascript value into a php variable without changing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I've got this *research.php* file that should show the content of a database table, taking the informations for the query from a javascript form.

I made in javascript the form and disabled the enter key, so that only by hitting the button you can submit the value. The value of the components in the form should be used to make the query. Can I pass the value to a php variable in the same file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<!--
    Implemented by Argese Alessandro and Rosso Kevin

    The slider is taken from "https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/samples/index.html"
    Download slider: "https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSlider/"
-->

    <title>Ricerca diplomati</title>

    (...) <!--slider things-->

    <style>
        (...)
    </style>

    <script>
        var mySlider;

        function doOnLoad(){ //slider load
            (...)
        };

        function doOnUnload(){ //slider unload
            (...)
        };

        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {

            // if the keyCode is 16 ( shift key was pressed )
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                // prevent default behaviour
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }

        });

        function interact(form){  
            (...) //here the value is put in js variables, for a test
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body onload="doOnLoad();" onunload="doOnUnload();">

    <form id="filters" name="filters" action="#" enctype="text/plain">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="filters_table">
            <tr>
                <td>Specializzazione:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="specialization" class="table">
                        <option selected value="0">Tutte le specializzazioni</option>
                        <option>Chimica</option>
                        <option>Elettrotecnica</option>
                        <option>Informatica</option>
                        <option>Meccanica</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Valutazione finale:</td>
                <td><div id="sliderObj"></div></td>
                <td><span id="sliderLink"></span><span class="minussign">-</span><span id="sliderLink2"></span></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Città:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="city" size="35" maxlength="40" value=""></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="interact(filters)" value="search" style="background: url(res/magnifying-glass-16x.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center; background-color: #0c84e4;width:24px; height:24px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <?php

        function viewTable(){
            echo "Here the table will be shown";
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

In this code the button click just call the *interact* function, that show an alert window with the value of the variables.

I tried to use ajax but, as far as I understood, it would open a new file.
I've also seen a solved answer in which someone suggested to use the cookies, but that solution really disgusted me.

The most helpful thing I found is here:
[How do i store select value into a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524405/how-do-i-store-select-value-into-a-php-variable),
but the POST method refresh the page and the slider crushes.

Comment: PHP is executed server side. You can only send you JavaScript veriable to PHP using AJAX if you do not want to reload the page.

Comment: What do you mean with 'ajax would open a new file'?
with ajax you can send a request to a php file and use its "answer" to modify your current (!) page however you like

Comment: I understood that with ajax you can only send informations to a php file, but not get any "answer" @Cashbee

Comment: `but not get any answer` ? The AJAX will get a response after it makes the request. Your server side code could put information into that response for the JS to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable from JS to PHP you are going to want to use AJAX, it allows you to send and receive info from server running the PHP script.

Your Javascript:

```
var infobeingsent = "test";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'YOURPHPFILE.php',
    data: { testVAR : infobeingsent },
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert("data has been sent");
        var recievedvar = data;
    }
});
```

Your php file:

```
if(isset($_POST['testVAR']))
{
    $recievedvar = $_POST['testVAR'];
    echo "Hey, ive recieved your request";
}
```

Using AJAX means that your browser never has to come into direct contact with the php file and there's no interruption from the end-users perspective

Comment: And how can I make the php file send back informations to ajax?

Comment: Yes, since the variable is now in your PHP script, you can access it like it was there to begin with.

Comment: You could also do this through the AJAX call using the variable "data" that was defined in my example

Comment: Added this to the example for you

Comment: I tried your solutions and it helped me really a lot. Just one last question: if I append the received variable to a div, in js, it will show all the content of the file .php (I'm using a webserver , so it should interpret the php). What could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about the whole work flow between php (server side) and js (client side). OR may be I got your question wrong. But here is a hint on how you can approach this.

1. You have a server side running php - Great.
2. You have an html page with js - Awesome.
3. In the html page, you have a form that you want to run a query based on the user submission:

AJAX is the way. You can do it with pure javascript or a plugin like jquery. On the php side, you can even keep a small, seperate script just to handle this request, run the query and generate the result. Use "onSubmit" for the form to invoke ajax.