# How can i save a <select> value in php variable?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass the value selected in `<select>` to the php variable `$selected_boutique` so that i can `echo` it in the `input`

I tried the solution given here : [How do i store select value into a php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524405/how-do-i-store-select-value-into-a-php-variable/21524497#) but it does not work for me, i also tried with `method = "get"`

Is there a way to get the selected option when the user changes the option without using a for and a submit?

```
<?php
  $selected_boutique = $_POST['num_boutique'];
?>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <li>
      <input id="boutique" type="text" value="<?php echo($selected_boutique);?>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <form action="" method = "post">
        <select name="num_boutique" id="num_boutique" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Zero</option>
          <option value="1">One</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </li>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you submit the form and check the variable?

Comment: How do you submit the form? There's no button? Also, `<li>` is useless without `<ul>`.

Comment: There should be something like this: `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`. Oh, and `value="<?php echo $selected_boutique; ?>">` (without `(` `)`)

Comment: If you also expect the text input (boutique) to be sent with the form, it needs to be inside the form.

Comment: I don't want it necessarily  in a form, i just want to retrieve the value when the user changes the option

Comment: You still need to send the value to PHP so using a form isn't a bad idea. But you still need to submit the form somehow before it can send anything. You might want to read up on [HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: You could use jquery

Answer (score 0):

This should do it -->

```
if(isset ($_POST['sub'])){
$selected_boutique = $_POST['num_boutique'];
}
echo "You have selected : ".$selected_boutique;
```

Also you need to add this to your form

```
<button type="submit" name="sub"></button>
```

Comment: This will not solve an issue. I tested on my local server and wrote a fix in a comment.

Comment: @GytisTG Sorry I was editing the comment. I did not know that he did not have a button.

Answer (score 0):

hello my friend please change your form tag and like below line

`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">`

And add button type submit in form

goodluck

Answer (score 0):

```
I am going to edit your code:
<?php
if(isset($_POST["num_boutique"])
$selected_boutique = $_POST['num_boutique'];
?>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <li>
  <input id="boutique" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["num_boutique"])    echo $selected_boutique;?>">
</li>
<li>
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELFT'] ?>" method = "post">
    <select name="num_boutique" id="num_boutique" class="form-control">
      <option value="0">Zero</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  </li>
 </header>
</body>

Remember:
When you want to put some php code at the top of the file and this code contains     POST or GET variables you should always put an "if(isset($_POST["example"]))" , because the GET and POST variables show up after you submit the form.
```

And in the "form" tag you should put as action ""